# Encountering `Service temporarily unavailable` Error When Inviting Collaborator via Facebook Reels API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Context**: I am working with the Facebook Graph API to create Reels on Facebook and subsequently invite collaborators. I'm following the steps outlined in the [Facebook Reels Publishing API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/). My process involves:

1. **Initializing an upload session** to get the video ID ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/#step-1--initialize-an-upload-session))
2. **Uploading the video** ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/#upload))
3. **Inviting a collaborator** ([docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/#invite-a-collaborator))

**Issue**: Steps 1 and 2 are successful. However, I encountered an issue during Step 3 (inviting a collaborator). When sending the POST request to invite a collaborator, I consistently receive a `Service temporarily unavailable` error.

**Request**:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/video-id/collaborators
  ?target_id=collaborators-page-id 
  &access_token=your-page-access-token"
```

**Error Message**:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "is_transient": true,
        "code": 2,
        "fbtrace_id": "AU_GbMZPNlOJaViwRTthC_-"
    }
}
```

**Attempts to Resolve**:

1. **Repeated Attempts**: I've tried repeatedly over the course of two weeks, assuming the issue might be temporary as indicated by the error message.
2. **Access Token Validation**: I am confident that my `access_token` is valid, as it works successfully for the first two steps (initializing upload session and uploading video).
3. **Target ID Variations**: I have attempted this with various `collaborators-page-id` values, ruling out the issue being specific to a single page.

**Questions**:

1. Has anyone else encountered this issue with the Facebook Reels API, particularly when inviting a collaborator?
2. Are there known issues or maintenance with this API part?
3. Any suggestions on alternative approaches or further steps I could take to resolve or debug this issue?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!